# Why to quote in dplyr and why not to quote in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am teaching an intro to R course and a student asked me a question that I cannot answer.
The question is, why do we not put `id` and `sex` in quotes after `select` in this example

```
df1 %>%
  select(id, sex)
```

but we put `id` in quotes after `inner_join` in this example

```
df1 %>%
       inner_join(df2, by = 'id')
```

The best I could come up with is because it `id` is after an `=` sign. But I imagine there is a better answer.

Comment: You *could* put columns in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the more general question, when do we use quoted column names as strings `“column_name”` and when do we use bare object names `column_name`:

In general the tidyverse uses non-standard evaluation and powered by this we can use bare object names as columns names `column_name` in most functions most of the time.

There are functions, such as `select` and `rename` which accept both:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select("hp") %>% 
  head()
#>                    hp
#> Mazda RX4         110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     110
#> Datsun 710         93
#> Hornet 4 Drive    110
#> Hornet Sportabout 175
#> Valiant           105

mtcars %>% 
  select(hp) %>% 
  head()
#>                    hp
#> Mazda RX4         110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     110
#> Datsun 710         93
#> Hornet 4 Drive    110
#> Hornet Sportabout 175
#> Valiant           105
```

And then there are functions which only accept strings. Up until v.1.0.10 we could only use string column names in the join functions.
I’d consider this as an inconsistency to most other tidyverse functions. Now we have `join_by()` which lets us use bare object names, as shown in the answer above.

I personally try to avoid string variable names `”column_name”` where possible to be consistent. String column names are needed when we create new columns which don’t exist yet, for example when we use `separate()` to create the columns `A` and `B`:

```r
df <- tibble(x = c("x.y", "x.z", "y.z"))
df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   A     B    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 x     y    
#> 2 x     z    
#> 3 y     z
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Reference for tidy evaluation:  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Spec for `inner_join`: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html

Basically, `inner_join`'s `by =`  argument takes "A join specification created with `join_by()`, or a character vector of variables to join by."

```
# character vector is your provided example
df1 %>%
       inner_join(df2, by = 'id')
# works

# join_by() form uses tidy evaluation
df1 %>%
       inner_join(df2, by = join_by(id))
# also works
```

Comment: It's ultimately a design choice, so the answer to "why" is really "because designer did it this way". Slightly more helpful maybe, the reason is historical: the join functions predate the tidy selection "revolution", and the recent `join_by()` argument was created to make up for it. However, `join_by()` has its own DSL, and doesn't use tidy selection nor data masking (the 2 documented types of tidy evaluation), so I believe the first link is misleading, though I wouldn't mind it be updated to include this new DSL as another kind of tidy evaluation.